# creating multiple restore points

Tags: postgresql

I am using the below command to create a restore point. However i'd like to create multiple restore  points and would like to know how not to overwrite the first one. Is there a way to add a counter after 'RP*' so it gives it a different number every time my shell script runs the below query?

```
select pg_create_restore_point('RP1');
pg_create_restore_point 
----------------------------
F3/D988F590
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to so that, unless you store the information about pre-existing restore points somewhere. The function just sets a marker with that name in the WAL. PostgreSQL doesn't remember restore points other than in the WAL.